# How to execute a callback inside a webassembly program?

Tags: scheme, emscripten, webassembly

I am working on scheme-to-javascript compiler. I am perusing the idea to target webassembly (wasm) instead.

**What I want is execute a callback that lives in a wasm program**, in particular I can not **only** rely on wasm `imports` or `exports`... but I might be wrong.

So far my experiments are all relying on scheme being translated to JavaScript or to webassembly but via emscripten.

In the case of JavaScript, DOM event can be bound to scheme procedure since scheme procedures are translated to JavaScript.

In the case of emscripten, I created two cooperative loops that rely on requestAnimationFrame. One lives in JavaScript the other in WebAssembly. The loop that lives inside WebAssembly rely on emscripten [Execution life-cycle functions](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/emscripten-runtime-environment.html#execution-lifecycle) to **pause** and **resume** the wasm program on-demand.

I think my question is how `emscripten_pause_main_loop()` and `emscripten_resume_main_loop()` are implemented and ultimately what is the execution strategy adopted by emscripten to allow JavaScript to resume wasm execution with some arguments.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The new thing is https://kripken.github.io/blog/wasm/2019/07/16/asyncify.html